# Tensorflow taking data size ( shape ) as dynamic and thus causing errors during node densing

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am training a model that the feature shape is [3751,4] and I'd like to use reshape and layer dense function built in Tensorflow to make the output labels have the shape [1,6].

The training and testing set are very similar, the only difference is that the testing data set has less batches than training set.

Now I am having two hidden layers in my model that will do something like:

```
input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [1,-1])
first_hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(input_layer, 4, activation=tf.nn.relu)
second_hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(first_hidden_layer, 5, activation=tf.nn.relu)
output_layer = tf.layers.dense(second_hidden_layer, 6, activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

This network structure is a function that both training and evaluating phase utilize.

Partial code for training is like :

```
 nn = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, params=model_params, model_dir='/tmp/nmos_self_define')

  train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": train_features_numpy},
      y=train_labels_numpy,
      batch_size = 3751,
      num_epochs=None,
      shuffle=False)

  # Train
  nn.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=5000)
```

And testing part is like:

```
test_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": test_features_numpy},
      y=test_labels_numpy,
      batch_size = 3751,
      num_epochs= 1,
      shuffle=False)

  ev = nn.evaluate(input_fn=test_input_fn)
  print("Loss: %s" % ev["loss"])
  print("Root Mean Squared Error: %s" % ev["rmse"])
```

During training, there is no problem, the function can reshape the input data and do the dense part. During the testing, however, the tensor shape of the reshape function gives something like [1,?], which is different from the training phase ([1,15004]). And this caused the tf.layers.dense functions to fail because it cannot do the dense without knowing the actual shape of the tensor.

The only difference between training and testing from my perspective is the num_epochs, but that shouldn't affect the input shape right? I don't understand why Tensorflow can reshape the tensor with solid values during training while it thinks the testing data input set are dynamic?

Please help and thanks for taking the time reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is flattening the input of multiple batches to a single feature vector of size 15004. What you are most probably trying to accomplish is to reduce the dimension of your feature to a 2D vector with shape (Batches, Nr Features), where Batches is dynamic. There are two common ways to do this. The easiest is to use the flatten layer from tf.contrib like this:

```
input_layer = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(features["x"])
```

or you can reshape in such a way that the batch dimension is still dynamic, but then you have to calculate the shape of your input like this:

```
num_dimensions = features["x"].shape.as_list[1] * features["x"].shape.as_list[2] ...
input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"], [-1, num_dimensions])
```

Comment: What is the difference between using flatten or the method I used ( reshape(features["x"],[1,-1]) ? I still don't understand why the training part works well and the testing part failed.

Comment: The difference is that flatten takes your batch shape into account. You should read up what dense layers actually do, then it makes more sense that it does not work.